# Retrieve data from mysql based upon a priority

Tags: mysql

I have 10 records in MySQL and suppose I want that 4th record should be on top and the remaining 9 are retrieved after the 4th.

```
Select * from info <what to put here> ??
```

I tried using this code but it's wrong

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno = 30 ORDER BY sno UNION ALL SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno = 30 ORDER BY sno
```

Comment: Could you please add an example, or an extract of the database

Comment: http://prntscr.com/el4597 

suppose i want to give priority to this record that it should be on top of the results which are retrived ,, how to do it ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM info WHERE sno = 30 ORDER BY sno
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM info WHERE sno = 30 ORDER BY sno;

Comment: 1. http://prntscr.com/el48xb

2. http://prntscr.com/el4926

Comment: @CounterAim why are you referencing images of code? that should be an edit to your question and using real code and not images of them.

Comment: Can you tell what's your table name?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array expects parameter 1 to be resource` error on line 326, look up that error.

Comment: your code is incomplete as per the `WHILE` loop. You're going to have to debug your code.

Comment: SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno = 30
UNION
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno != 30;

Comment: @Alex my table name is profiles

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno = 30 ORDER BY sno UNION ALL SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno = 30 ORDER BY sno;");

Comment: @CounterAim: use this: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno = 30 UNION SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno != 30;");

Comment: will this work ? $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno = 30 AND sec = 'Y' AND title  =  'Secretariat ' UNION SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno != 30  AND sec != 'Y' AND title  !=  'Secretariat ';");

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = 4
UNION
SELECT * FROM info WHERE id != 4;
```

Later edit, based on new information

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno = 30
UNION
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE sno != 30;
```

Comment: UNION will probably reorder the result set. You should at least use UNION ALL. However a specific order is never guaranteed withot an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
select * from info where sno = 4
UNION ALL 
select * from info where sno <> 4
```

First, I select only the row number 4, then I just add all the remaining rows by using `<>` which means different of.
The `UNION ALL` do the union between the 2 select

Comment: `!=` is valid in MySQL. So your answer is a copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ***sure*** that you need **exactly** the 4th element, just get the data from the database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM info;";
```

Then while printing print `$elemets[3]` first (as $elements[0] is the first row that is fetched) and then do `unlink($elements[4]);` and print the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean expression for the order. `sno = 30` will return `1` for that specific row and `0` for all other rows. So you can use it for descending order.

```sql
Select * 
from info
order by sno = 30 desc, sno
```